# return Json array from PHP mySQL - Error

Tags: php, mysql, json

Here is my php code and i want to get JSON array relevant to to my $_GET("ProductGroup") variable. but when i log in to the page by submitting parameters via URL
http://iilsfa.br0s.info/SFA/get_all_products.php?%27Laptops%27 it displays this error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

i could not find where the error is. please help

```
<?php
 include_once './db_connect.php';

function getProducts(){
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
// array for json response
$response = array();
$response["products"] = array();

// Mysql select query

// check for post data
 if (isset($_GET["ProductGroup"])) {
$selected_group = $_GET['ProductGroup'];
}


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductType= $selected_group")or die(mysql_error());


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    // temporary array to create single category

    $tmp = array();
    $tmp["id"] = $row["ProductID"];
    $tmp["name"] = $row["ProductName"];
    $tmp["type"] = $row["ProductType"];
    $tmp["image"] = $row["ProductImage"];
    $tmp["des"] = $row["ProductDescription"];


    // push category to final json array
    array_push($response["products"], $tmp);
}

// keeping response header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// echoing json result
echo json_encode($response);
 }

 getProducts();
 ?>
```

PS- I have changed my sql query to this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductType=   '".mysql_real_escape_string('$selected_group')."'")or die(mysql_error());
```

Now its not displaying the previous error.but showing an empty json string. i have checked SQL query with phpmyAdmin.it working correctly and produce results..

Comment: _See the single quotes ?_ `ProductType= '$selected_group'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this below. Dont use simple query. See SQL injection. [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://pk1.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to prevent from sql injection

```
<?php
 include_once './db_connect.php';

function getProducts(){
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
// array for json response
$response = array();
$response["products"] = array();

// Mysql select query

// check for post data
 if (isset($_GET["ProductGroup"])) {
$selected_group = $_GET['ProductGroup'];
}


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductType= '".mysql_real_escape_string($selected_group)."'")or die(mysql_error());


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    // temporary array to create single category

    $tmp = array();
    $tmp["id"] = $row["ProductID"];
    $tmp["name"] = $row["ProductName"];
    $tmp["type"] = $row["ProductType"];
    $tmp["image"] = $row["ProductImage"];
    $tmp["des"] = $row["ProductDescription"];


    // push category to final json array
    array_push($response["products"], $tmp);
}

// keeping response header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// echoing json result
echo json_encode($response);
 }

 getProducts();
 ?>
```

Comment: i have changed my code in to this                                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductType= '".mysql_real_escape_string('$selected_group')."'")or die(mysql_error());                                                    but now the JSON array is empty..can you help..you can see the results by above url..

Comment: @san88 Please check record in database relevant to selected ProductType found or not?

Comment: yes..database contains 5 records for Laptops keyword and when i execute the sql command in phpMyAdmin, its working correctly..

Comment: just echo ("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductType= '".mysql_real_escape_string($selected_group)."'"); and see the query and then run this query in db?

Comment: i have add these lines   echo "this is a test";
echo ("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductType= '".mysql_real_escape_string($selected_group)."'");
but still not working... you can see the results by using this url  http://iilsfa.br0s.info/SFA/get_all_products.php?%22Laptops%22    please help

Comment: try to use simple query $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Product") or die(mysql_error()); then see its working or not, may be databse connection problem.

Comment: i found the error.its happen because im using wrong url to return data..thanks for helping friend.

Answer (score 2):

Quote the parameters...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductType= '$selected_group'")or die(mysql_error());
```

---

You must not use **mysql_***.
Also look at [**mysqli_real_escape_string**](https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)

Answer (score 2):

First, your code is well documented, even for a starter, not too much, just only on places where it's required.

Now, your error lies in the query itself.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductType= $selected_group")or die(mysql_error());
```

If a field in the query is of type string, you must add single quotes around it, or the interpreter will think that you're looking for a column name. Here below is a solution.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductType= '$selected_group'")or die(mysql_error());
```

But i would add that your query is not secure. It allows SQL injection, which can harm your database data. for further information about SQLi, please refer to [this page](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)

You can go for [`mysqli()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions, which is an improved version of the `mysql()`-functions. Although i recommend to use [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.